# Implementing button release for a stopwatch with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have designed a program that allows three buttons to control a stopwatch:

- Start button, starts the timer: Canvas turns green (in progress), if timer reaches 15 seconds canvas will turn red.
- Stop button, resets the timer: Canvas turns yellow (idle).
- Emergency Stop button: When pressed, pauses timer (canvas turns orange). When released, resumes timer (canvas turns green).

Currently the Start & Stop buttons work fine. But the Emergency Stop (pause & resume) is where I am having issues.

If I start the timer say for 5 seconds and then press the Emergency Stop button to pause the timer, the timer does pause, but releasing the button causes the program to loop in the section that prints "Release" and doesn't restart the timer.

I am expecting the release of the Emergency Stop button to resume the timer turning the canvas green if below 15 seconds.

I am having struggle debugging the program as once in a tkinter loop you can't really see what buttons are being selected and where you are going with the program.

Here is the code I have written for this:

```
class StopWatch(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        
        self._timer_text = tk.StringVar()
        self._timer_text.set("00:00:00")
        self._canvas_color = tk.StringVar()
        self._canvas_color.set("yellow")
        self.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)
        
        self.timer_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self._timer_text, font=("Helvetica", 48))
        self.timer_label.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=100, height=100, bg="yellow", highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10

        GPIO.add_event_detect(14, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.start, bouncetime=50)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(15, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.reset, bouncetime=50)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.pause, bouncetime=200)

    def _update(self):
        """Update the timer label with elapsed time."""
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._timer_text.set(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(self._elapsedtime)))
        if self._elapsedtime > 15:
            self.canvas.config(bg='red')

        if self._running:
            self.after(100, self._update)

    def start(self, channel):
        """Start the stopwatch."""
        self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
        self._running = 1
        self.canvas.config(bg='green')
        self._update()

    def pause(self, channel):
        """Pause the stopwatch."""
        self._running = 0
        self.canvas.config(bg='orange')
        eStop_flag = True
        
        while eStop_flag == True:
            print("Stop flag True")
            time.sleep(0.2)
            if GPIO.input(21) != GPIO.LOW:
                print("Emergency Stop")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                eStop_resume = False
                while eStop_resume == False:
                    if GPIO.input(21) != GPIO.HIGH:
                        print("Released")
                        eStop_resume == True
                        time.sleep(1)
            eStop_flag == False
        self.start(channel)
            
    def reset(self, channel):
        """Reset the stopwatch."""
        self._start = time.time()
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._timer_text.set("00:00:00")
        self._running = 0
        self.canvas.config(bg='yellow')
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Stopwatch')
    root.geometry('500x200')
    stopwatch = StopWatch(root)
    stopwatch.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: By "button", do you mean Tkinter buttons or physical buttons? What is `GPIO`?

Comment: If you trigger `pause` on a falling edge, shouldn't you be checking if the input is `LOW` for "Emergency Stop" and `HIGH` for "Released"`?

Comment: Also note that assignments are done with `=`, not with `==`.

Comment: Yes these are physical buttons. The eStop button is checking if its pressed when it is not LOW. And not High when released. Also thanks for the assignments, i know its =, just got confused, Seems to be working now lol, such a simple fix

Comment: In line 21, missing brace bracket at  the end `self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10`. Should be `self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra Apologies, its fine in my original code. I cut parts out to display relevent parts

Comment: @CrankyJack. Are you using Raspberry Pi?. I can see window with yellow rectangle and stopwatch.

Comment: `while eStop_flag == True`: should be `while == True:`

Comment: In line 53, should be `if not GPIO.input(21):`

Comment: Comment out line 58. You don't need nest `while/else` condition.

Answer (score 1):

In the pause function you are using double equals instead of a single one. It should look like this:

```
def pause(self, channel):
    """Pause the stopwatch."""
    self._running = 0
    self.canvas.config(bg='orange')
    e_stop_flag = True                # Variables should be lowercase

    while e_stop_flag:                # This is a Boolean variable, so you don't  
                                      # need a conditional statement
        print("Stop flag True")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if GPIO.input(21) != GPIO.LOW:
            print("Emergency Stop")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            e_stop_resume = False
            while not e_stop_resume:    # Same here (but use "not")
                if GPIO.input(21) != GPIO.HIGH:
                    print("Released")
                    e_stop_resume = True  # this should set the var so use = 
                    time.sleep(1)
        e_stop_flag = False               # Same here
    self.start(channel)
```

(I don't know what GPIO is)